# Text not displaying on desired position on onclick

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

I am trying to divide the web page into two columns and display text with `onclick`. My html is:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
    <head>
      <title>My first styled page</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle.css">

     </head>

     <body>
      <div id="container">
      <div id="header">
      <h1>Main Title of Web Page</h1>
          Here I am trying to split the webpage into two columns and display text.
      </div>
          <div id="one">
      </div>
          <div id="two">
       <b>This is test one<br>
       <b>This is test two<br>
           </b>
      </div>
     </div>

     <script src="script.js"></script> 
   </body>

    </html>
```

My `script.js`file is:

```
 var wrapping_div = document.createElement('div');
    document.body.appendChild(wrapping_div);

    function shuffleArray() {
        var i, j, temp, span, div,
            c = wrapping_div.childNodes, 
            l = c.length,
         array = ['abc','xyz','mno'], 
        k = array.length;
    for (i=k-1; i>=0; i--) {
            j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
            temp = array[i];
            array[i] = array[j];
            array[j] = temp;
        }

    for (i=l-1; i>=0; i-- ) {
            c[i].firstChild.removeEventListener('click', shuffleArray);
            wrapping_div.removeChild(c[i]);
        }

    for (i=0; i<k; i++) {
            span = document.createElement('span');
            span.innerHTML = array[i];
            span.addEventListener('click', shuffleArray);
            div = document.createElement('div');
            div.appendChild(span);
            wrapping_div.appendChild(div);
        }
    }

    shuffleArray();
```

My css file is:

```
     #container {
     width:100%;
     height:200px;
     }

  #header {
    margin-bottom:0;
    background-color:red;
   }

 #one {
    width:40%;
    height:200px;
    float:left;
    background-color:yellow;
   }

#two {
   width:60%;
   height:200px;
   float:left;
   background-color:cyan;
   }

 #one > span {
   display:block;
   }
```

Now, my problem is that I am not able to display the array elements on the right side of the page, means I want to display it within the `div` id `one`. Also, I want on each `onclick` event the new array elements should replace the previous array elements. How can I display the array elements within the `div` id `one`?

Currently, my array elements are getting displayed below the `div` id `one`, means below the `yellow` color. I want it to be displayed within the `yellow` color. My elements are getting updated on each `onclick` but I am unable to display the array elements on the `div` id of `one`.

Below is the link to the `jsfiddle`: http://jsfiddle.net/rani89/X8YEG/

Comment: A jsfiddle would be nice

Comment: @TejasPatel fiddle added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, it's your lucky day and I got you again!
See [DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Godinall/Dq8Pz/)

You are using the wrong wrapping div that's your problem.

```
//var wrapping_div = document.createElement('div'); Remove this
var wrapping_div = document.getElementById('one'); Add this
//document.body.appendChild(wrapping_div); Remove this
```

And when you are using the right wrapping div, you don't need to create extra div

```
//div = document.createElement('div'); Remove this
        div.appendChild(span);
        //wrapping_div.appendChild(div); Remove this
```

Comment: Just noticed that same mistake.

Comment: @user2567857 did my above answer solve your problem?

Comment: No, it's showing me `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeEventListener' of null`. This error is not showing in `fiddle` but I am getting that error in my server. It's showing that error in `js` file of line `c[i].firstChild.removeEventListener('click', shuffleArray);`

Comment: @user2567857 that's strange, did you try the new demo above or the previous demo? As it works perfect on my side?

Comment: Yes, in fiddle it works but in local server I had to remove the `removeEventListener` line, only then it's working. Will see if removing that line provides any error in further development.